# I want to go the previous MENU whenever I press the physical back button on my droid, could someone guide me through that ?

Tags: java, android

This is my Function that dynamically create menu from a parsed XML, now I want that when I press the physical back button it should move to the previous menu.
I have read a lot of articles on this but still haven't find a single for going back in Menus.

```
public int create_menu(int level_n){

    int lv=level_n;


    if(flag){
        base=0;
    }
    else{
        base=lv-1;
    }
    ctr=true;
    if(e[lv].getType().equals("menu")){
        flag=false;
        subm[lv]=subm[base].addSubMenu(0, lv, 0, e[lv].getName());
        lv++;




        for(int i=0;i<noChild[lv-1];i++){
            if(e[lv+i].getType().equals("menu")){

                create_menu(lv+i);
                Log.i(TAG,"number=  "+i);
                flag=false;

            }
            else if (e[lv+i].getType().equals("action")){
                if(ctr){
                Log.i(TAG,"going to else"+e[lv].getName()+"   " +i);
                subm[lv]=subm[lv-1+i].addSubMenu(0, lv+i, 0, e[lv+i].getName());
                //Log.i(TAG,"element = "+e[lv+1].getType() );


                lv++;
                create_menu(lv);
                ctr=false;
                }

                flag=false;
            }
        }
        flag=true;

    }
    else if(e[lv].getType().equals("action")){
        if(flag==true && ctr==true)
        {
            subm[lv]=subm[base].addSubMenu(0, lv,0, e[lv].getName());
            lv++;

        }
        else if(flag==false && ctr==false){
            subm[lv]=subm[base-1].addSubMenu(0, lv, 0, e[lv].getName());
            lv++;

        }

    }

    return lv;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `KeyEvent`, try the below...

```
public boolean onKeyUp( int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp( keyCode, event );
    }
```

Comment: i want to go back in a menu. I am having 3 level menu, so can you please explain it to me, how should I use this function for my benefit. Thanks

Comment: This code is for you Hardware Back Button on the Phone, which when pressed go back to the previous Activity... Above is just an Example... If you want to use it for Menu, remove the finish() and implement your code there

Comment: I tried but it is not helping, where should i implement this??

Comment: See this link...it will help  http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/example-code-for-onkeydown-listener-in.html